# Best practices on implementing text components from scratch

Tags: user-interface, graphics, osdev, window-managers

I've written a [kernel with a small userspace](http://ghostkernel.org/), and currently I'm in the process of writing a window manager (from scratch). I made a library for basic drawing, ported `freetype2` for text rendering and the windowing/input system/basic components work fine.

Buttons and other basic stuff are not very hard, but text components have a lot more requirements - they need to be fast, allow text selection (view-model/model?) and other stuff, and should be extendable in the sense of allowing a program to add whatever funky stuff it needs (like, maybe emoticons) into the text.

Where can I find out about best-practices when implementing good-performing/extendable text components?

Comment: Dear close-voter, why did you vote for close? I wouldn't have asked this question if it was that easy to find information on this specific topic... :/

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."

Comment: meanwhile you are waiting some good answer, you can take a look at : (glui_edittext.cpp) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/glui/ you may find useful tips.

Comment: While the question has likely been answered by now, a useful source of insight into such compoonents can be the Wine sources for Linux, which implement a compatibility layer for Windows programs. Wine includes all of the long-existing common controls in windows and a number of the newer (after comctrl.dll v6) The sources can be found here: https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/tree/master/dlls/comctl32 Do note: some components ae not implemented in `comctrl.dll`, but are instead found in user32.dll and others are elsewhere.